# Showing the percentage of poll's progress bar outside progress bar

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using this code for my web assignment: 
http://csstechniques.blogspot.sg/2007/05/super-simple-css-bars.html

But how do I show the percentage of the bar outside the progress bar like so: [image]?

I've tried many ways & it is driving me nuts. I've also googled but most results comes up using jQuery, which I'm not supposed to use for my assignment (only CSS, HTML and PHP).

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You need JavaScript. This isn't possible with pure CSS.

Comment: Thanks for answering! But, erm, PHP isn't the same as JavaScript right? I can also use PHP for my assignment.

Comment: No PHP (server-side) is not at all the same as JavaScript (client-side). But it's also solvable in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your html is like this:

```
<div class="progress-container">
  <div style="width:95%"></div>
</div>
```

you will need additional elements to show the percentage text like so:

```
<div class="progress-container">
  <div style="width:95%"></div>
</div>
<p class="percentage-text">
  <span class="percentage-number">95</span>%
</p>
```

Then you can query the percentage-number element and change the text with JavaScript like so:

```
var number = 95; // this is the same number you are using to change the graph.
var perc = document.querySelector(".percentage-number");
perc.innerHTML = number;
```

Check out [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelector), querySelectorAll, getElementById, getElementsByTagName, etc. in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).  That will help you quite a bit with this.  By the way, querySelector and querySelectorAll only work in modern browsers (incl. IE8+).  That's one of the reasons why people use jQuery to do this stuff.

Comment: oh i didn't see that you can't use javascript.  yes, you can put the text of the percentage in the PHP template.  something like this: <p class="percentage-text"><?php echo($percentage); ?>%</p>

Comment: THANK YOUUUUU! It works!! I can now finish my assignment & sleep in peace lol.